# Allow (De)Activating only for users with specified field security profile

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm looking for the best way to forbit (de)activating a record for users that do not have a specified field security profile.

My approach was to display/hide activate/deactivate button depending on the users profiles. And add a synchronous plug-in that checks security profiles when (de)activating a record.

Is there a simpler way? With this approach I have to edit 6 button commands (hompage grid, form, subgrid - activate and deactivate button) and I have to create a new plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have covered all the bases. The most fail safe way would be with a plugin that runs pre operation and checks the security role. From a user point of view it would return an error which might scare them. By hiding the buttons you remove that problem but have to be careful to make sure you remove them from all places you can deactivate a record.

I would say to do both if you want to be sure.

Comment: You also think there is no simpler way?

Comment: Not that I can see without it being open to errors. I would say your way is robust and also by hiding the buttons nice to the users